# Jquery add and remove multiple input count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems with multiple input count numbers with jQuery. When I read it with barcode, new inputs are formed in the lower and the counter is increasing. But when I remove one of them, the counter does not give the correct number.

**I want :** when I delete an input, refresh all input counts.

My Fiddle : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toplumdusmani/5nggyjbq/10/)

My Code:

```js
$('#giris').keypress(function(e){
  if (e.which == 13) {
  $ney = $(this);
  var neymis = $ney.val();
  if (neymis != '' || neymis != NULL) {
  var wrapper = $('.listele');
  var say = $( "#inputsay input" ).size();
  wrapper.append('<tr id="in_'+say+'"><td>'+say+'</td><td><input class="form-control input-sm duz'+say+' lan" type="text" value="'+neymis+'" name="mlzm[]" id="in_'+say+'" data-id="'+say+'" disabled="true"></td><td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" id="sil" data-id="'+say+'">Remove</button></td></tr>');
  $('#giris').val('');
  $('#say').html(say);
  }
  }
});


$( document ).on( 'click', '#sil', function () {
      var sil_id = $(this).data("id");
      var silinen = $(".duz"+sil_id).val();
      $("#in_"+sil_id).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputsay">
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="giris" placeholder="Seri no.." ng-keydown="keydown($event)">

<div class="table-responsive mb-lg">
  <table class="table table-bordered mb-none">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Serial Num.</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="listele"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

var say = $( "input" ).size()-2;

//bu şekilde yapacağına inputlara bir class ver

var say = $( ".input_class" ).length

//yaparsan ekleme ve çıkarma da herzaman doğru sonucu alırsın

Comment: I try : $('.sayac').text(function(index, prevText) {
   if(sil_id < say){
            return parseInt(prevText, 10) - 1;
   }
   }); but not working

Comment: I agree with @Ionut you [should use English on SO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/)

Comment: Please indent your code by four spaces and translate your comments to English.

Comment: I updated my fiddle link. I want : when user delete an input, refresh all input counts.